# Laravel Tinker ErrorException with message 'Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, tinker

I have a laravel application deployed on a kubernetes cluster
when i try to use laravel tinker im getting below error after hitting enter for every command

```
ErrorException with message 'Undefined variable: status'
```

on my local machine there is no such problem at all

im stuck at debuggin this. how can i get error trace to find out where this is happening

Laravel 5.6
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.1.33 — cli)

Comment: There should be a full stack trace logged, tracking it down depends on how you have logging configured, but very possibly in storage/log/laravel.log or storage/log/laravel-2020-03-10.log ?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper my laravel logs works as expected , same about php-cli logs.the problem is this error is not logged in any of these places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours digging in psysh source code, i found the problem.

i had some `pcntl_xxx` functions disabled in my php.ini file, removed them and everything works fine now.

by the way, for anyone interested the exact path of where this error happened :

in `vendor/psy/psysh/src/ExecutionLoop/ProcessForker.php` file look for private function called `createSavegame()`

Comment: Thanks for the update! PsySH was checking whether `posix` and `pcntl` extensions were available before enabling the process forker, but it wasn't robust enough. I just pushed a change that checks not only that the extensions are enabled, but that none of the required functions are disabled. It'll be available in the next stable release! https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/commit/bdfe05cbe4a229b0ebeadbad5b1af112df3d4068